# BitLocker Raid5 encrypted disk was moved to another server of the same type

Tags: encryption, raid, bitlocker, windows-server-2012-r2, raid-5

Has anyone tried or simulated moving a Raid5 encrytped disk (BitLocker) to another server with same family? What are your observations and what was the impact?

For example:
the server RAID disk(1x) has been stolen and the thief inserted it in the same type of RAID server. A very good thief actually has the same type of server with 1 slot available, the disk was inserted in that available slot.

We know the disk is locked by the BitLocker and the data will not be accessible.
We knew that a thief can reformat the disk to re-use it, but in this case the thief hasn't formatted it yet and has inserted it in a server. What will be the impact?

a) The impact on the thief's server?

b) The impact on the disk with BitLocker?

c) Will the disk affect the thief's server's RAID logical drive?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drive will just show up uninitialized or possibly be recognized as a separate, broken RAID array.

Regardless, one disk in a RAID 5 array is not enough to recover information unless it is a chunk of data smaller than the stripe size - and that is if it wasn’t encrypted.

The other server will not recognize nor use the drive in anyway until it is reinitialized and added to an existing or new array at which point it will be wiped.

Good news for you is, if only one drive was “stolen” you can just replace it and rebuild the array and move on.

Comment: Thank you very much Appleoddity for the response, this makes clear now.

Comment: Hi All, if you would also visit "Impact of Bitlocker deployment on logical disk and OS (root)" thanks for your time. link: https://superuser.com/questions/1272398/impact-of-bitlocker-deployment-on-logical-disk-and-os-root