# Impact and observations of encrypted disks (Bitlocker) on WANSync servers

Tags: security, bitlocker, disk-encryption, windows-server, deployment

Has anyone tried to encrpyt disk drives of a WANSyncHA Servers?

We used Arcserve WANSync to our DB servers and we are planning to encrypt both the primary and secondary disks using a Bitlocker.

We would like to know the impact when all disks (primary & secondary) were encrypted:

1. Is this possible and what will be the impact?
2. When the time failover comes, are there any impact?
3. Any observations to those who experience encrypting drives on WANSync servers?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: BitLocker can only be applied by the Windows operating system, and only to storage it is directly connected to (not to network drives, etc.). I've never used WANSync but unless a Windows machine can access the drives directly (via SATA, SCSI, USB Mass Storage, etc.) it's not going to be able to encrypt them that way.

Comment: do you think bitlocker would work on high availability servers? Thanks CBH